# How to share persistent storage between isolates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-sharedpreference

I am using [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) to run a dart isolate. In that isolate, I modify some data and I want those changes to reflect in the main isolate. Likewise, I want changes made in the main isolate to reflect in the alarm isloate.

### What I have tried

Currenlty I am using [get_storage](https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_storage) to save and read data. But it isn't synchronizing between isolates.

#### Alarm isolate

```dart
await GetStorage.init();

// Some time later
GetStorage().write("data", data);
```

#### Main Isolate

```dart
await GetStorage.init();

// This read always occurs after the write in the alarm isolate, but it still doesn't reflect the changes made in that write.
GetStorage().read("data");
```

Before this, I was using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to do the same. `shared_preferences` actually had a reload method which was supposed to synchronize from disk, but I am not sure how to use it in my use case.

I have also tried the ugly method of writing and reading data to a file manually. This works, but is probably slow and I have to make sure that writes don't overlap (I would prefer not to use synchronous writes since it will block the UI).

Comment: It's impossible to share memory across isolates, since each isolate has its own memory. This is intentional and by design, as shared memory is very error-prone. If you want to have a system that synchronizes data across isolates, you would need to create that system yourself using the `SendPort` and `ReceivePort` of each isolate communicating back to a central place that propagates changes out to all the other ones. It will not be straightforward, and you will run into that error-prone issue.

Comment: @Abion47 But is it also a bad idea to share storage between them?

Comment: Storage is just another name for memory (in this context), so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) for persistent storage in Flutter. It uniquely offers built-in threading support, enabling easy database operations across isolates with no extra effort.

You might also want to explore the sqlite_async package, which you can find at https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite_async. This package is specifically designed to run SQLite operations on a separate isolate, ensuring that your UI remains responsive during database transactions.

By utilizing these tools, you can perform database operations asynchronously, thereby keeping your application's interface smooth and responsive even during extensive database interactions.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No, I have no affiliation with the Drift library or its creators. My recommendation is purely based on my personal experience as a developer. After struggling for many days with similar issues in Flutter Dart, I found Drift to be a highly effective solution. My intent is solely to assist fellow developers in the community by sharing practical solutions that worked for me. Cheers:)